# On-demand converting collection wrapper

Tags: c#, collections

Before I reinvent the wheel, is there anything in the .NET framework that already does what I'm after:

I have an `IList<TypedObject>` which loads data on demand from disk (millions of rows available).  I want to bind that list to a WPF control, however each object needs to become a `TypedObjectDisplayer`.

The WPF control needs to take a complete list, as it needs to know how many records are available to display correctly, which I think rules out using LINQ.

I was going to create an `IList<TypedObjectDisplayer>`, which wraps an `IList<TypedObject>`, converting as each one is requested by the indexer using a definable delegate.  Does the .NET framework already offer something like this?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, was just working out how to do that myself!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, no.

I had to do something similar a while back and did a lazy conversion with a wrapped collection.